# Recommend Software or Techniques to plot multiple items on x-axis

Tags: python, r, excel, plot, plotly

I need to plot two variables(Fruits, Vegetables) on X axis and the prices on y axis, for multiple states.

What kind of plot do you recommend?

Comment: Stacked Bar Plots, Plotly library can be used in R programming to plot such graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Try on of the following Libaries:

Mathplot (https://matplotlib.org/)
Plotly (https://plot.ly/python/)

Comment: Works Fine on Plotly